# How to correctly detect hdmi port in 14.04 with onboard radeon 1200 to enable hdmi audio?

Tags: 14.04, sound, ati, hdmi

After upgrading from 12.04, i get no audio device from HDMI. Altough the display itself is working, seems that it doesn't even detect it as HDMI, but as DVI instead:

```
mrguga@mrguga-server:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
   1920x1080      50.0*+   60.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9
```

Altough resolution and display is alright, there is no HDMI sound device:

```
mrguga@mrguga-server:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Changing drivers is not an option, I'm stuck with opensource ones since AMD does not support this device since 8.04.

I tried lots of things from google, no success. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I know you do not with to install the drivers, but [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Unsupported_Chips) it is given that the device (Radeon X1200) is fully supported. Try installing the driver...

If you get the drivers, HDMI Audio can be manually set with the following cmd:

```
echo "options radeon audio=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf
```

There could be a work around if the device was present in the list of playback devices, see [this](http://www.benjiegillam.com/2008/10/working-hdmi-audio-on-ati-graphics-card/).